# Cocoa sheet shows up in a random place

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion

I'm trying to create a sheet that I'm loading from a custom nib file and has it's own Window Controller. In my app delegate upon a button press, I call

```
- (IBAction)loginLogout:(id)sender {
    if (![self isLoggedIn]) {
        // need to login
        LoginManager *manager = [[LoginManager alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"LoginSheet"];
        [manager presentLoginWithWindow:self.window];
    }
}
```

Then in the window controller (the LoginManager class), I have this

```
- (void)presentLoginWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window {
    if (!self.window) {
        [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"LoginSheet" owner:self];
    }

    [NSApp beginSheet:self.window modalForWindow:window modalDelegate:self didEndSelector:@selector(didEndSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:) contextInfo:nil];
}
```

But I end up with this.

[image]

Comment: I'd bet the 'random' location of the sheet corresponds directly to the location specified in the nib. @omz's answer should take care of you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you left the sheet window's "Visible At Launch" option checked in Interface Builder?

Comment: Wow, great. What an easy fix!